# pipenv does not install properly on Python 2.7.10 on Mac OS X 10.10.6 El Capitan

Tags: python, macos, python-2.7, pip, pipenv

I'm working on a talk for my Python user group that deals with the pipenv package.

I'm definitely running into trouble trying to get this to work. I'm working with the instructions over at the [Hitchhiker's Guide to Python](http://docs.python-guide.org/en/latest/dev/virtualenvs/) as a reference.

Here's my installation command with its output:

```
➜  ~ sudo -H pip install --user pipenv
Collecting pipenv
  Using cached pipenv-8.2.2.tar.gz
Requirement already satisfied: virtualenv in /Library/Python/2.7/site-packages (from pipenv)
Requirement already satisfied: pew>=0.1.26 in /private/var/root/Library/Python/2.7/lib/python/site-packages (from pipenv)
Requirement already satisfied: pip>=9.0.1 in /Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pip-9.0.1-py2.7.egg (from pipenv)
Requirement already satisfied: requests>2.18.0 in /private/var/root/Library/Python/2.7/lib/python/site-packages (from pipenv)
Requirement already satisfied: flake8 in /private/var/root/Library/Python/2.7/lib/python/site-packages (from pipenv)
Requirement already satisfied: urllib3>=1.21.1 in /private/var/root/Library/Python/2.7/lib/python/site-packages (from pipenv)
Requirement already satisfied: pathlib; python_version == "2.7" in /Library/Python/2.7/site-packages (from pew>=0.1.26->pipenv)
Requirement already satisfied: shutilwhich; python_version == "2.7" in /Library/Python/2.7/site-packages (from pew>=0.1.26->pipenv)
Requirement already satisfied: backports.shutil-get-terminal-size; python_version == "2.7" in /Library/Python/2.7/site-packages (from pew>=0.1.26->pipenv)
Requirement already satisfied: pythonz-bd>=1.10.2 in /Library/Python/2.7/site-packages (from pew>=0.1.26->pipenv)
Requirement already satisfied: virtualenv-clone>=0.2.5 in /Library/Python/2.7/site-packages (from pew>=0.1.26->pipenv)
Collecting setuptools>=17.1 (from pew>=0.1.26->pipenv)
  Using cached setuptools-36.5.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Requirement already satisfied: idna<2.7,>=2.5 in /private/var/root/Library/Python/2.7/lib/python/site-packages (from requests>2.18.0->pipenv)
Requirement already satisfied: chardet<3.1.0,>=3.0.2 in /private/var/root/Library/Python/2.7/lib/python/site-packages (from requests>2.18.0->pipenv)
Requirement already satisfied: certifi>=2017.4.17 in /private/var/root/Library/Python/2.7/lib/python/site-packages (from requests>2.18.0->pipenv)
Requirement already satisfied: pyflakes<1.6.0,>=1.5.0 in /private/var/root/Library/Python/2.7/lib/python/site-packages (from flake8->pipenv)
Requirement already satisfied: enum34; python_version < "3.4" in /private/var/root/Library/Python/2.7/lib/python/site-packages (from flake8->pipenv)
Requirement already satisfied: configparser; python_version < "3.2" in /private/var/root/Library/Python/2.7/lib/python/site-packages (from flake8->pipenv)
Requirement already satisfied: pycodestyle<2.4.0,>=2.0.0 in /private/var/root/Library/Python/2.7/lib/python/site-packages (from flake8->pipenv)
Requirement already satisfied: mccabe<0.7.0,>=0.6.0 in /private/var/root/Library/Python/2.7/lib/python/site-packages (from flake8->pipenv)
Installing collected packages: pipenv, setuptools
  Running setup.py install for pipenv ... done
Successfully installed pipenv-8.2.2 setuptools-36.5.0
➜  ~ pipenv
zsh: command not found: pipenv
```

I've tried various permutations of the installation command and have added the `/Users/<my username>/Library/Python/2.7/bin` directory to my `.zshrc` as a part of the PATH. Here's the output of `python -m site`:

```
➜  ~ python -m site
sys.path = [
    '/Users/<my_name_here>',
    '/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pip-9.0.1-py2.7.egg',
    '/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python27.zip',
    '/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7',
    '/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/plat-darwin',
    '/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/plat-mac',
    '/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/plat-mac/lib-scriptpackages',
    '/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python',
    '/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/lib-tk',
    '/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/lib-old',
    '/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload',
    '/Users/<my_name_here>/Library/Python/2.7/lib/python/site-packages',
    '/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/PyObjC',
    '/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages',
]
USER_BASE: '/Users/<my_name_here>/Library/Python/2.7' (exists)
USER_SITE: '/Users/<my_name_here>/Library/Python/2.7/lib/python/site-packages' (exists)
ENABLE_USER_SITE: True
```

What am I missing here? Is this something I should refer to the developers?

EDIT:

Running without --user and only sudo, here are my results:

```
➜  ~ sudo -H pip install pipenv
Requirement already satisfied: pipenv in /private/var/root/Library/Python/2.7/lib/python/site-packages
Requirement already satisfied: virtualenv in /Library/Python/2.7/site-packages (from pipenv)
Requirement already satisfied: pew>=0.1.26 in /private/var/root/Library/Python/2.7/lib/python/site-packages (from pipenv)
Requirement already satisfied: pip>=9.0.1 in /Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pip-9.0.1-py2.7.egg (from pipenv)
Requirement already satisfied: requests>2.18.0 in /private/var/root/Library/Python/2.7/lib/python/site-packages (from pipenv)
Requirement already satisfied: flake8 in /private/var/root/Library/Python/2.7/lib/python/site-packages (from pipenv)
Requirement already satisfied: urllib3>=1.21.1 in /private/var/root/Library/Python/2.7/lib/python/site-packages (from pipenv)
Requirement already satisfied: pathlib; python_version == "2.7" in /Library/Python/2.7/site-packages (from pew>=0.1.26->pipenv)
Requirement already satisfied: shutilwhich; python_version == "2.7" in /Library/Python/2.7/site-packages (from pew>=0.1.26->pipenv)
Requirement already satisfied: backports.shutil-get-terminal-size; python_version == "2.7" in /Library/Python/2.7/site-packages (from pew>=0.1.26->pipenv)
Requirement already satisfied: pythonz-bd>=1.10.2 in /Library/Python/2.7/site-packages (from pew>=0.1.26->pipenv)
Requirement already satisfied: virtualenv-clone>=0.2.5 in /Library/Python/2.7/site-packages (from pew>=0.1.26->pipenv)
Collecting setuptools>=17.1 (from pew>=0.1.26->pipenv)
  Using cached setuptools-36.5.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Requirement already satisfied: idna<2.7,>=2.5 in /private/var/root/Library/Python/2.7/lib/python/site-packages (from requests>2.18.0->pipenv)
Requirement already satisfied: chardet<3.1.0,>=3.0.2 in /private/var/root/Library/Python/2.7/lib/python/site-packages (from requests>2.18.0->pipenv)
Requirement already satisfied: certifi>=2017.4.17 in /private/var/root/Library/Python/2.7/lib/python/site-packages (from requests>2.18.0->pipenv)
Requirement already satisfied: pyflakes<1.6.0,>=1.5.0 in /private/var/root/Library/Python/2.7/lib/python/site-packages (from flake8->pipenv)
Requirement already satisfied: enum34; python_version < "3.4" in /private/var/root/Library/Python/2.7/lib/python/site-packages (from flake8->pipenv)
Requirement already satisfied: configparser; python_version < "3.2" in /private/var/root/Library/Python/2.7/lib/python/site-packages (from flake8->pipenv)
Requirement already satisfied: pycodestyle<2.4.0,>=2.0.0 in /private/var/root/Library/Python/2.7/lib/python/site-packages (from flake8->pipenv)
Requirement already satisfied: mccabe<0.7.0,>=0.6.0 in /private/var/root/Library/Python/2.7/lib/python/site-packages (from flake8->pipenv)
Installing collected packages: setuptools
  Found existing installation: setuptools 1.1.6
    Uninstalling setuptools-1.1.6:
Exception:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pip-9.0.1-py2.7.egg/pip/basecommand.py", line 215, in main
    status = self.run(options, args)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pip-9.0.1-py2.7.egg/pip/commands/install.py", line 342, in run
    prefix=options.prefix_path,
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pip-9.0.1-py2.7.egg/pip/req/req_set.py", line 778, in install
    requirement.uninstall(auto_confirm=True)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pip-9.0.1-py2.7.egg/pip/req/req_install.py", line 754, in uninstall
    paths_to_remove.remove(auto_confirm)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pip-9.0.1-py2.7.egg/pip/req/req_uninstall.py", line 115, in remove
    renames(path, new_path)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pip-9.0.1-py2.7.egg/pip/utils/__init__.py", line 267, in renames
    shutil.move(old, new)
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/shutil.py", line 299, in move
    copytree(src, real_dst, symlinks=True)
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/shutil.py", line 208, in copytree
    raise Error, errors
Error: [('/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/_markerlib/__init__.py', '/tmp/pip-WRGjnq-uninstall/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/_markerlib/__init__.py', "[Errno 1] Operation not permitted: '/tmp/pip-WRGjnq-uninstall/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/_markerlib/__init__.py'"), ('/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/_markerlib/__init__.pyc', '/tmp/pip-WRGjnq-uninstall/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/_markerlib/__init__.pyc', "[Errno 1] Operation not permitted: '/tmp/pip-WRGjnq-uninstall/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/_markerlib/__init__.pyc'"), ('/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/_markerlib/markers.py', '/tmp/pip-WRGjnq-uninstall/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/_markerlib/markers.py', "[Errno 1] Operation not permitted: '/tmp/pip-WRGjnq-uninstall/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/_markerlib/markers.py'"), ('/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/_markerlib/markers.pyc', '/tmp/pip-WRGjnq-uninstall/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/_markerlib/markers.pyc', "[Errno 1] Operation not permitted: '/tmp/pip-WRGjnq-uninstall/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/_markerlib/markers.pyc'"), ('/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/_markerlib', '/tmp/pip-WRGjnq-uninstall/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/_markerlib', "[Errno 1] Operation not permitted: '/tmp/pip-WRGjnq-uninstall/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/_markerlib'")]
```

and without sudo:

```
➜  ~ pip install --user pipenv
Collecting pipenv
  Using cached pipenv-8.2.2.tar.gz
Requirement already satisfied: virtualenv in /Library/Python/2.7/site-packages (from pipenv)
Requirement already satisfied: pew>=0.1.26 in ./Library/Python/2.7/lib/python/site-packages (from pipenv)
Requirement already satisfied: pip>=9.0.1 in /Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pip-9.0.1-py2.7.egg (from pipenv)
Requirement already satisfied: requests>2.18.0 in ./Library/Python/2.7/lib/python/site-packages (from pipenv)
Requirement already satisfied: flake8 in ./Library/Python/2.7/lib/python/site-packages (from pipenv)
Requirement already satisfied: urllib3>=1.21.1 in ./Library/Python/2.7/lib/python/site-packages (from pipenv)
Requirement already satisfied: pathlib; python_version == "2.7" in /Library/Python/2.7/site-packages (from pew>=0.1.26->pipenv)
Requirement already satisfied: shutilwhich; python_version == "2.7" in /Library/Python/2.7/site-packages (from pew>=0.1.26->pipenv)
Requirement already satisfied: backports.shutil-get-terminal-size; python_version == "2.7" in /Library/Python/2.7/site-packages (from pew>=0.1.26->pipenv)
Requirement already satisfied: pythonz-bd>=1.10.2 in /Library/Python/2.7/site-packages (from pew>=0.1.26->pipenv)
Requirement already satisfied: virtualenv-clone>=0.2.5 in /Library/Python/2.7/site-packages (from pew>=0.1.26->pipenv)
Collecting setuptools>=17.1 (from pew>=0.1.26->pipenv)
  Using cached setuptools-36.5.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Requirement already satisfied: idna<2.7,>=2.5 in ./Library/Python/2.7/lib/python/site-packages (from requests>2.18.0->pipenv)
Requirement already satisfied: chardet<3.1.0,>=3.0.2 in ./Library/Python/2.7/lib/python/site-packages (from requests>2.18.0->pipenv)
Requirement already satisfied: certifi>=2017.4.17 in ./Library/Python/2.7/lib/python/site-packages (from requests>2.18.0->pipenv)
Requirement already satisfied: pyflakes<1.6.0,>=1.5.0 in ./Library/Python/2.7/lib/python/site-packages (from flake8->pipenv)
Requirement already satisfied: enum34; python_version < "3.4" in ./Library/Python/2.7/lib/python/site-packages (from flake8->pipenv)
Requirement already satisfied: configparser; python_version < "3.2" in ./Library/Python/2.7/lib/python/site-packages (from flake8->pipenv)
Requirement already satisfied: pycodestyle<2.4.0,>=2.0.0 in ./Library/Python/2.7/lib/python/site-packages (from flake8->pipenv)
Requirement already satisfied: mccabe<0.7.0,>=0.6.0 in ./Library/Python/2.7/lib/python/site-packages (from flake8->pipenv)
Installing collected packages: pipenv, setuptools
  Running setup.py install for pipenv ... done
Exception:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pip-9.0.1-py2.7.egg/pip/basecommand.py", line 215, in main
    status = self.run(options, args)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pip-9.0.1-py2.7.egg/pip/commands/install.py", line 342, in run
    prefix=options.prefix_path,
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pip-9.0.1-py2.7.egg/pip/req/req_set.py", line 784, in install
    **kwargs
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pip-9.0.1-py2.7.egg/pip/req/req_install.py", line 851, in install
    self.move_wheel_files(self.source_dir, root=root, prefix=prefix)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pip-9.0.1-py2.7.egg/pip/req/req_install.py", line 1064, in move_wheel_files
    isolated=self.isolated,
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pip-9.0.1-py2.7.egg/pip/wheel.py", line 345, in move_wheel_files
    clobber(source, lib_dir, True)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pip-9.0.1-py2.7.egg/pip/wheel.py", line 323, in clobber
    shutil.copyfile(srcfile, destfile)
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/shutil.py", line 83, in copyfile
    with open(dst, 'wb') as fdst:
IOError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/Users/am034402/Library/Python/2.7/lib/python/site-packages/setuptools-36.5.0.dist-info/RECORD'
```

Answer (score 1):

You should not be using both `sudo` and `--user`  here; that causes it to be installed for the super user only.

Either just use `sudo`, in which case it will be installed globally, or use `--user`, so it will be installed just for your user.

Comment: see post edits for updates. doing it without these two modifiers together results in issues.

Comment: Does your advice apply when using the macOS default Python, brew (or port) installed Python, or always?

Answer (score 0):

Ultimately this issue was solved by upgrading to OS X 10.12 Sierra. With the various programs and libraries available as of this writing (Sept 29, 2017) there seem to be issues with the use of pipenv on El Capitan.

Answer (score 0):

Ran into similar issue. Infuriating. I think I figured out what's going on here.

TL;DR: Don't use the 'sudo -H' and 'pip --user' flags together.

Using 'sudo -H' tell changes the user home directory '~' to '/private/var/root', so pip caches, installs stuff in '/private/var/root/Library/Python/2.7/lib/python/site-packages' instead of '/User/nerdenator/Library/Python/2.7/lib/python/site-packages'. Which then confuses pip.

Access to '/private/var/root' is (necessarily) locked down. To clear that unintentional cache, I nervously used 'sudo rm -rf /private/var/root/Library/Python/2.7/lib/python/site-packages', which seems to have gotten me back on track.

I have no idea where I picked up the 'sudo -H pip install .... --user' tip. But 'sudo -H' and 'pip install ... --user' most definitely shouldn't be used together on macOS.

YMMV.